# LiveChatMessages API YouTube returns null

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am trying to get messages from the live chat chat using a GET request.

```
$json_result = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveChat/messages?liveChatId=$videoId&part=snippet&key=$api_key");
// $videoId и $api_key true, there are no errors.
echo '<pre>';
var_dump(json_decode($json_result));
echo '</pre>';
```

In the answer I get NULL, tell me what is the error or what method can I get messages from the YouTube broadcast chat?

Comment: json_decode returns NULL when it has an error parsing the json. file_get_contents can return false if it has an error while trying to fetch the results. It might help to print both of those values to see where the error lies.

Comment: @GertdePagter, file_get_contents returns false, yes, but I still don’t understand what could be the error ...

Comment: You could try dumping the results of [`error_get_last()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php). That can give you an indication of what the exact fault is.

Comment: @GertdePagter, `["message"]=>
  string(232) "file_get_contents(https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveChat/messages?liveChatId=[ID_VIDEO]&part=snippet&key=[API_KEY]): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found` such a mistake.

Comment: The URL is rejected by www.googleapis.com. It seems that partly the [Live Streaming API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/) is currently not working. File this with [Google](http://issuetracker.google.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it will be useful for someone, solved the issue through `cURL` instead of `file_get_contents`.

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveChat/messages?liveChatId=$LiveChatId&part=snippet%2CauthorDetails&maxResults=200&key=$api_key");
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'JeezLand API');
$json_results = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
$json_decode_results = json_decode($json_results);
foreach($json_decode_results as $json_decode_result){
    foreach($json_decode_result as $result){
        /* echo '<pre>';
            var_dump($result);
        echo '</pre>'; */
        echo $result->authorDetails->displayName.' -> '.$result->snippet->displayMessage.'<br />';
    }
}
```

Special thanks to [Gert de Pagter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10121049/gert-de-pagter) for the help on solving the problem.

Comment: is this still working for you?  have you tried inserting a message into chat?